# Can't update a chosen property of an Object. why?

Tags: javascript

This is a fun little example I have decided to use to practice somethings and for some reason it is not working as I had hoped it would. What I wanted was to chose a stat to update besides  defense and lvl. For sake of this I will always chose str. What I noticed was that for some reason, it wouldn't update `person.str` when I chose it.

```
function levelUp(person){
    var inc = prompt("What stat shall we increase other than defense?");
    console.log(inc);
    console.log(person.inc);
    var lvl = parseInt(person.lvl,10);
    lvl++;
    person.lvl=lvl;
    var def= parseInt(person.def,10);
    def++;
    person.def=def;
    var stat=parseInt(person.inc,10);
    stat++;
    person.inc=stat;

}

var die={
str:10,
def:6,
spd:8,
lvl:1
};
console.log(die.lvl);
console.log(die.str);
console.log(die.def);
levelUp(die);
console.log(die.lvl);
console.log(die.str);
console.log(die.def);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`person.inc` is referring to the `inc` field of `person`, which does not exist.

You should use `person[inc]` instead.